# Why is it reverted/cancelled?

Tags: transactions, uniswap, python, failed-transaction, revert

Executions usually reverted (it transact, deduct fee but fail).

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1ba2897733c8aacecad59593dd66ed333156645cb1c5d604a45524c9de34f91b

```
version = 2
provider = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/myinfura"
eth = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
uniswap = Uniswap(address=address, private_key=private_key, version=version, provider=provider)
uniswap.make_trade(eth, coin, 110**16, slippage=0.9, fee=current_gas_price*1.5)
```

why? (especially by relatively new coins (couple hours), but they have liquidity and no honeypots)
Thanks,

Comment: looks like sub underflow to me.. there are some cases when liquidity gets in such proportions that swap gets failed while conversion